# Converting Oracle queries to MSSQL queries dynamically

Tags: sql, oracle

i have alot of queries that are written in oracle and i wish to convert them to mssql queries. (Not database migration, but actual query to query)

Is there any good and easy way to do it over a large sum of queries? Even 1 by 1 would be nice.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Do you need a one-time conversion, or is it more of an ongoing process?

Comment: Try here : http://www.sqlines.com/online

Comment: @Mansoor I have tried sqlines, but its just not good enough. it fails to convert to_date

Comment: @FrankSchmitt its an ongoing process. i need this because some data is kept in the database as queries and these queries obviously didnt convert to sql queries while migrating..

Comment: If there was a tool to reliably do this, do you have any idea how much Microsoft would pay for it? a lot. SQL is complicated. Some Oracle features aren't available in SQL Server either. Like `CONNECT BY` and some analytical functions. IF you have very simple queries you could just replace the oracle functions with sql server functions.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't seen such tool. It should be possible to accomplish it using a stored procedure.